# how to correctly add a listener to a button on Android Studio SDK 29

Tags: java, android

Listener to the "back" button:

```
btnTroVe.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
            }
        });
```

The exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
```

Comment: Did you make sure to do the connection between the button in the class and the xml by using findViewById method?
As I understand it, you trying to access a listener of something that is not defined and thats why you get null object.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, please include more code so we can understand and debug your issue, normally this is caused due to a `null` Object, please make sure that your `btnTroVe = findViewById(R.Id.ObjectIDInXML`) exists.

Comment: how to you find btnTroVe? I mean when you call findViewById and what xml of content view?

Comment: I have successfully repaired. thanks everyone.